# I want to know distinction between functions taking const or nonconst parameters

Tags: c++

As I have seen from `C++ Primer,fourth edition`,

> **"What may be surprising, is that although the parameter is a const inside the function, the
>   compiler otherwise treats the definition of fcn as if we had defined the parameter as a plain int:"**

```
void fcn(const int i) { /* fcn can read but not write to i */ }

void fcn(int i) { /* ... */ } // error: redefines fcn(int)
```

So, if I want to define two functions as follows,

```
int func(const int i) { 
    return i;
}

int func(int i){
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

Actually,they are two different functions,but when I compile it,there is a message:`error:redefinition of 'int func(int i)'`.Can I define them like this? Is there any alternative methods?

Comment: They are two definitions of the same function (`int func(int)`), as explained in the paragraph you quoted. There's no way around that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are passing by value, so you won't change the original value in either case. You are just saying that the temporary value copied into the function won't change in the function. The caller would have no way to determine which one to call.

Comment: What part of "although the parameter is a const inside the function, the compiler otherwise treats the definition [...] as if we had defined the parameter as a plain in" is it that is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter passed by value (like your int) are copied onto the stack,
then if your function takes a 'const int' as an argument, it does not change what can be done from outside the function (it justs forbids you from changing the value inside the function). Since the parameter is copied, a function that takes an int as an argument can be called on a const int (it will not modify the argument since it gets a copy).

Since there is no difference 'seen from outside' of the function between the one that takes an int and a const int, there would be no reason for the compiler to choose one version or the other, this is why the C++ norm states that it is the same function.

Now if you have a function that takes a reference f(int &) and another one that takes a const reference f(const int&), it is another story: then only the second one can be called with a const int argument like in:

```
const int x=5;
f(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

const just modifies how you access your variable it doesn't change its data type, as far as the compiler is concerned both of them are integers and that's how they are stored whether modifiable or not.

The only workaround i see is to overload the function by changing the data type of your parameter, maybe long, double, byte etc..